# Calculate velocity vector along a curve (as a function of time)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

I have a curve defined by an equation: $y = f(x)$

In my case, the equation is a polynomial $y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$.

I also have $2$ boundary conditions. Point $A$ and Point $B$. I know the velocity and position of $A$ and $B$ and I know the time taken to travel from $A$ to $B$ along the curve. With some simple calculus I have been able to the determine the variables, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. This means I know $\dfrac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}= f'(x)$ and $y=f(x)$.

What I really want to know is position and velocity as a function on time:
\begin{align*}
  \dot{x} &= v_x(t) \\
  \dot{y} &= v_y(t) \\
  x &= x(t) \\
  y &= f(x(t))
\end{align*}

How would I determine this for either my polynomial or for an equation $y=f(x)$?

Comment: What properties of $A$ and $B$ is known? velocity, . .

Comment: Yes, we know the position and velocity at both points $A$ and $B$. We also know the time taken to travel from $A$ to $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using cubic spline:**

\begin{align*}
  p(x) &=
   \frac{x-b}{a-b}f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b) \\
  & \quad +
  (x-a)(x-b)\left \{
              \frac{x-b}{(a-b)^{2}} \left[ f'(a)-\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} \right]+
              \frac{x-a}{(b-a)^{2}} \left[ f'(b)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right]
            \right \} \\[5pt]
  p'(x) &=
  \frac{x-b}{a-b}f'(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}f'(b)+
  3(x-a)(x-b)\left \{
               \frac{f'(a)+f'(b)}{(b-a)^2}-\frac{2[f(b)-f(a)]}{(b-a)^3}
             \right \}
\end{align*}

> Note that $p(x) \equiv f(x)$ if $f(x)$ is a cubic (or lower) polynomial, else $p(x)$ is just an interpolating polynomial.

**Boundary conditions:**

- $A=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ f(a) \end{pmatrix}$
- $B=\begin{pmatrix} b \\ f(b) \end{pmatrix}$
- $\boldsymbol{v}_A=\dfrac{v_A}{\sqrt{1+f'(a)^2}}
      \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ f'(a) \end{pmatrix}$
- $\boldsymbol{v}_B=\dfrac{v_B}{\sqrt{1+f'(b)^2}}
      \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ f'(b) \end{pmatrix}$

where $y$ is a single-valued function of $x$.

> **Caution:**
>   $a$, $b$ here are **NOT** the coefficients of the cubic polynomial but two distinct boundaries.

In general for space curve,
\begin{align*}
  \boldsymbol{p}(t) &=
   \frac{t-b}{a-b}\boldsymbol{x}(a)+\frac{t-a}{b-a}\boldsymbol{x}(b) \\
  & \quad +
   (t-a)(t-b)
   \left \{
     \frac{t-b}{(a-b)^{2}}
     \left[
       \boldsymbol{x}'(a)-\frac{\boldsymbol{x}(a)-\boldsymbol{x}(b)}{a-b}
     \right]+
     \frac{t-a}{(b-a)^{2}}
     \left[
       \boldsymbol{x}'(b)-\frac{\boldsymbol{x}(b)-\boldsymbol{x}(a)}{b-a}
     \right]
   \right \}
\end{align*}

Comment: I assume you are using the same cublic spline equation i described above. Why is the solution independent of variables $c$ and $d$?

How do I use this solution to find $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity, regard $a$ and $b$ as $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Answer updated.

Comment: Great - that has cleared it up a lot. You are an absolute champion.

I think one final question. The final equation returns $p(t)$. The position should be defined by both an $x$ and $y$ coordinate. What exactly is $p(t)$ and how can be used to give $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Just repeat the procedure component by component:
$$\boldsymbol{p}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} p_x(t) \\ p_y(t) \\ p_z(t) \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\boldsymbol{x}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \\ z(t) \end{pmatrix}$$